# How can I upgrade Kotlin version from 1.2.51 to 1.3 on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having some trouble upgrading the version of Kotlin to `1.3-M1` or `1.3-M2`

I'm using `1.2.51` right now and the error I'm getting when I try using any newer versions like `1.3-M2` is:

`Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3-M2.`

I'm guessing it has been moved but I've looked al over and haven't found a solution.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is no Kotlin version 1.2.7; the available versions are 1.2.70 and 1.2.71.

Comment: Made an edit to clarify that I need a newer version than 1.2.7+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to yole and TheWanderer I found what was missing.

[Here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin) under the `EAP-NEXT` tab you can find the correct version of the kotlin plugin for IntelliJ/Android Studio.

So this is what I did to solve it:

1 - `Android Studio -> Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates`
2 - Select Early Access Preview 1.3 on the `Update channel` drop down(If you can't find it click again)
3 - What [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52726227/2144418) says:
On your project level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
  }
}

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To update to a prerelease version of Kotlin, as described in the [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/09/kotlin-1-3-rc-is-here-migrate-your-coroutines/#how-to-try),  you need to add the `kotlin-eap` repository to your build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
  }
}

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
}
```

Comment: I had actually seen that post and tried that but on the wrong gradle file

Answer (score 2):

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.7
```

Doesn't exist. The plugin versions use trailing zeros, so it would be:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.70
```

However, `1.2.71` is currently the latest, so I recommend using that instead.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin

Comment: Sorry, the question was kind of miss leading, I'm actually trying to update to a 1.3.+ version

Comment: There's no such thing. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin

Comment: Kotlin 1.3 may be released, but there is no Kotlin 1.3 plugin for IntelliJ yet.

Comment: There most definitely is one. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/update/50621 for example.

Answer (score 0):

I just change 1.2.x version of kotlin in my gradle file like this and it worked:

```
buildscript 
{
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: This is an old question and I was working with unreleased versions of Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

To update to a prerelease version of Kotlin, you need to add the kotlin-eap repository to your build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
        repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    
      repositories {
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
      }
    }
    
    repositories {
      maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    }
```